# laravel Auth::user() returns null after authentication

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-authentication, laravel-authorization

I am getting Auth::user() null in a controller. After logging in with credentials i normally get the authenticated user data but in one of my projects i am not getting the authenticated user data.

For explanation i am posting the code snippets.
In NewLoginController i try to attempt the login using credentials and it is successfully logging in when i try with credentials and i can see the admin view, but when i try to go to homepage using /homepage route i get Auth::check() false and not be able to maintain the flow of the application, while in my other projects it is the same flow i have used.

Can any one guide me resolving this issue ?

```
class NewLoginController extends Controller
{
    public function attemptLoginApi()
    {
       
        if (Auth::attempt(['username' => request('username'), 'password' => request('password')])) {
            
            $userType = Auth::user()->user_type;
             return view('admin');
        } else {
         
            toastr()->error('Invalid Credentials', 'Error');
            return back();
        }

    }

}


class HomePageController extends Controller
{

    public function getUserHomepage()
    {
        
        if (Auth::check()) {
            
            return view('admin');
        
        } else {
         
             return view('home');

        }
        
    }
    
}
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/homepage', 'HomePageController@getUserHomepage');
Route::post('/loginApi', 'NewLoginController@attemptLoginApi')->name("loginApi");
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have forgotten to use `Auth` middleware. Put your `homepage` route in a route group that uses `Auth` middleware. See the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-group-middleware) .

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>'auth'],function () {
    Route::get('/homepage', 'HomePageController@getUserHomepage');
});
```

Comment: Hi .. thanks for the reply. 
I made changes according to your code, but its still the same happening.

Comment: any more suggestions ??